# Prove that $X= \{(x_1,x_2) : (x_1-2)^4+(x_2-\cos(x_2))^4 \le 1\} $ is a closed bounded set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that $X=\{ (x_1,x_2) : (x_1-2)^4+(x_2-\cos(x_2))^4 \leq 1\} $ is a closed bounded set

I've begun to study Topologie and I just have only one idea: it's to prove that every sequence $(x_n)_n$  in X converges to a limit $a$ then $a \in X$. But I don't know how to do this. Does it have another way to prove that a set is closed or open?

Comment: It is closed because it is the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function of two variables.

Comment: Thank you but can you please explain more details? I can't find the inverse image that you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$f \colon {\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}, \quad (x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1 - 2)^4 + (x_2 - \cos(x_2))^4$$
is continuous. Your set is the preimage of the closed subset $(-\infty, 1]$ of ${\mathbb R}$ under this map; therefore it is closed.

It is bounded because it is contained in $[-1,3] \times [-2,2]$.